# Something similar in with HTML5,ASP.NET/PHP and MySQL / SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, xml, html, canvas

I am asking this question again because it was stated I was unclear the first time round so here it goes.

As a Flash developer I can use Flash as my front-end

Use ASP.NET or PHP where I process my business logic and sometimes output the results in XML format which will be integrated with the Flash frontend.

Use MySQL or SQL Server as my backend

My question is can HTML5 (Canvas feature specifically) be used to achieve the same effects such as located at www.hochspunnung.dk (photo grid effect  with preloading) while using  PHP or ASP.NET and SQL to do the backend processing ?

Comment: Ok thanks and sorry about the site. it was actually  http://www.hochspannung.ch/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can.

Canvas can be used to do nearly anything Flash can do. The limitations on canvas are that in dealing with high framerates or very complex images (or anything requiring scene graph effects--remembering what/where images are) Flash may be more effective.

[Creating a picture gallery with html5 canvas](http://www.ubelly.com/2011/01/creating-a-picture-gallery-with-html5-canvas/)

This is one project that is similar to what you're asking. The back-end is unimportant.